# getting a double backslash when decoding URL Query

Tags: iphone, ios, url-scheme

I'm trying to decode a url query for my iphone app.

Here's the code I use

```
    - (NSDictionary *)parseQueryString:(NSString *)query {

    NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[pairs count]];

    for (NSString *pair in pairs) {

        NSArray *elements = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
        NSString *key = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *val = [elements objectAtIndex:1];

        [dict setObject:val forKey:key];

    }
    return dict;
}
```

Here's the query string that I've been feeding in.

```
station=124&serverip=demo\sqlexpress&username=test&password=noneofyourbusiness&serviceip=anumber&useimages=true&imagepath=pathforimages
```

When I NSLog the returned dictionary the server ip comes out as

```
serverip = "demo\\sqlexpress";
```

Suddenly it has two backslashes instead of one.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your strings are probably fine. Logging a dictionary prints does not print strings as they are.

Printing a dictionary converts it to the old [`NSPropertyListOpenStepFormat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000942-SW1) format. Strings use a backslash for escaping there.